# In the Cauchy Integral Formula generalisation of analytic functions to matrix functions is it acceptable to let the curve not enclose all eigenvalues?

Tags: matrices, complex-analysis, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, cauchy-integral-formula

Let $U\subset\Bbb C$, and let $f:U\to\Bbb C$ be holomorphic on $U$ and continuous on $\overline{U}$, with $U$ a simply connected open subset. Let $\gamma$ be a closed curve in $U$, of winding number $1$ about the point $z\in U$. Then:

$$f(z)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{\gamma}\frac{f(w)}{w-z}\,\mathrm{d}w$$

Let $A$ be a square matrix, and $I$ the identity matrix of the same dimensions. Then if $\gamma$ *encloses all eigenvalues* (from Wikipedia and other sources) of $A$, $f(A)$ can be defined as:

$$f(A)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_\gamma f(w)(wI-A)^{-1}\,\mathrm{d}w$$

And the logic for this is, I believe, that if $w\in\gamma$ were ever an eigenvalue of $A$, the expression $(wI-A)^{-1}$ would not exist by definition and the integral formula would fail to be well defined. However, the sources I read never explained this requirement, so my guess could be way off the mark.

Letting $\gamma$ enclose all eigenvalues so that $w$ is comfortably never an eigenvalue, $\forall w\in\gamma$, is a straightforward way to keep the integral well defined. However, I wonder in the interests of rigour, could I have a path $\gamma$ such that $\forall w\in\gamma,\exists(wI-A)^{-1}$ but some eigenvalues of $A$ are *not* enclosed. For example, if $A$ had eigenvalues $(1+2i,3,-i)$ and if $\gamma$ was the open disk of radius $\frac{1}{2}$ about the origin, $\gamma$ would enclose no eigenvalues, but no eigenvalues would lie on $\gamma$, and to my mind this would keep the integral well defined, since $A$ isn't exactly a point in the interior of $\gamma$ so $\gamma$'s placement is less important.

Are there any problems here I'm overlooking?

EDIT: One user has pointed out in the comments that there must be at least one singularity in the interior of $\gamma$ for the integral to be non-zero, so my new question is: if we let $\gamma$ enclose only *one* eigenvalue, so that the integral is non-zero but many eigenvalues are *not* enclosed, would this still be well-defined or a good generalisation?

Comment: No!  It is important that $\gamma$ has winding number $1$ or else $\int_\gamma f(w)/(w-z)\,\mathrm{d}w=0$, which mean you lost all information about this eigenvalue and eigenspace.

Comment: @user10354138 So the Cauchy Integral Theorem readily generalises to matrices, then? Would letting $\gamma$ enclose a single eigenvalue, so that the integral is definitely non-zero, be enough?

Comment: No!  For example, let $f\colon\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ be the identity and you don't enclose an eigenvalue, say the eigenvalue $2$ for the $2\times 2$ matrix $A=\operatorname{diag}(1,2)$ but does for the other eigenvalue $1$.  Then $\int_\gamma f(w)(wI-A)^{-1}\,\mathrm{d}w=\operatorname{diag}(2\pi i, 0)$, not $\operatorname{diag}(2\pi i,4\pi i)=2\pi i A$.

Comment: @user10354138 I appreciate your point now, and believe that you are correct. In my note taking however, how do I justify this? I could write " we lose information " but that doesn't quite make sense to me, formally. The spectrum of a matrix must lie in $U$ because... because excluding an eigenvalue from $U$ yields the integral for a different matrix? I'm hazy on this

Comment: @user10354138 ah! Is it because any analytic function has the property $f(A)=f(MJM^{-1})=Mf(J)M^{-1}$, seen by the power series expansion, and to properly represent $f(J)$ all the diagonal entries, the eigenvalues, must be accounted for? $J$ is the Jordan form and $M$ is a modal matrix